# Can I ping Google with a sitemap from another domain

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

I already know that a `Sitemap.xml` file can be hosted on a different website and point to it via the `robots.txt` file like so

#### In `awesomewebsite.example/robots.txt`

```
Sitemap: https://sitemaphost.example/awesomewebsite/sitemap.xml
```

### Google Ping

Now regarding the Google Ping, could `sitemaphost.example` ping Google with a simple GET request

```
# from sitemaphost.example server
GET https://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=https://sitemaphost.example/awesomewebsite/sitemap.xml
```

I've read the docs but couldn't find clear information about the origin of the ping.

It's also possible that the ping is useless because the sitemap is referenced in `robots.txt` file - can someone confirm this?